# Webpack too many arguments provided

Tags: webpack

I am trying to run webpack but when I do webpack via terminal I am just receiving this error message saying

Too many arguments provided. Expected max 2 but received 3.

loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: What is the command you type in the terminal? And what version of webpack are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

webpack v3.2.0

webpack-dev-server v2.5.0

using below commands:

sudo npm install webpack@3.2.0 --save-dev

sudo npm install webpack-dev-server@2.5.0 --save-dev

to fix issue of 
YError: Too many arguments provided. Expected max 2 but received 3

Comment: Please don't just post a link as an answer. Quote the main parts of it in case the link stops working.